# Why won't this simple Morte program typecheck?

Tags: haskell, types, morte

I'm trying to better understand the Calculus of Constructions through Morte. My first attempt was to call the identity function itself. However,

```
(
λ (idType : *) →
λ (id : idType) → 
(id idType))

(∀(t : *) → ∀(x : t) → t)
(λ(a : *) → λ(x : a) → x)
```

That program fails to compile with the error:

```
Context:
idType : *
id : idType

Expression: id idType

Error: Only functions may be applied to values
```

That doesn't make sense to me, since `id` is the function `(λ(a : *) → λ(x : a) → x)`, of type `idType == (∀(t : *) → t → t)`. Why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that with Church-style typing (here is a nice [blogpost](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2015-09-27-flavors.html) and some [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/dependent_types/comments/3moqoo/two_flavours_of_type_theory/)) everything must be well-typed from the beginning: if you have a well-typed `f` and a well-typed `x`, then you can apply `f` to `x` (if types match). If `f` is not well-typed, then it's not a legal term and you have an error, even if it is possible to assign `f x` a type.

Your `λ (idType : *) → λ (id : idType) → (id idType)` is not well-typed: `id` is a term of type `idType` and it's not a function that receives `*`, so you can't apply it to `idType`.

Comment: You both tell me it is not well-typed but neither explains exactly why it is not well-typed, nor how it should be done.

Comment: @Viclib, Morte and me told you that `id : idType` doesn't have a functional type and hence you can't apply it to `idType` — this is the precise reason, why the term is ill-typed. What should be done? Do you want a function application operator such that you can write `apply id (∀(t : *) → ∀(x : t) → t)`?

Comment: But I don't understand why doesn't it have a functional type. `idType == (∀(t : *) → ∀(x : t) → t)` after applying the first lambda, so it is a functional type, isn't it?

Comment: @Viclib, because every subexpression must be (with Church-style typing) well-typed before any reductions at the value level. You're trying to apply `λ (idType : *) → λ (id : idType) → (id idType)` to two arguments, but this function is ill-typed, and it doesn't matter what the arguments are — you have an error anyway.

Comment: Okay it makes sense this way.

Comment: @Viclib Compare it with Haskell `let f :: forall a::*. a -> Int ; f x = x in f 4` (with explicit type arg: `... in f Int 4`). This is "dynamically well typed" since we only apply it to `Int`, but statically it is rejected.

Comment: @Viclib, [this](http://lpaste.net/145437) should typecheck. We ensure that `id` is a function that receives `*`. `idType` becomes a function that returns a type (rather than just a type) to reflect the fact that the type signature for `id` is partially defined as `∀(t : *) → ...`. I'd suggest to use Agda instead of Morte: basic syntax of Agda is almost the same, but everything is easier, when you have the opportunity to name terms.

Comment: But isn't Agda overly featured? If it has way too many shortcuts, I'm afraid it might compromise my ability to actually understand the underlying system. Moreover, isn't Agda's system different (I'm aware of 2, Martin Lof and CoC). Also, why particularly Agda instead of Idris?

Comment: @Viclib, I guess, basic Idris is indistinguishable from basic Agda (except that Agda treats universes more explicitly, which is good for learning), so it fits too. Yes, there are implicit arguments in both Idris and Agda, which simplify things a lot, but you can just not use them. I don't know whether Morte has the `* : *` rule, but if so, you can write at the top of an Agda file `{-# OPTIONS --type-in-type #-}` to enable this rule. Other basic rules should be the same.

Comment: Okay, I want to ask some questions about your suggestion, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I shouldn't post it here on comments (may be off-topic / chatty), nor create a new question (possibly off-topic for SO itself).

Comment: @Viclib, you can write me at effectfully@gmail.com. But I'll be busy for the next two hours.

Answer (score 4):

Your

```
T = (λ (idType : *) →
     λ (id : idType) → 
    (id idType))
```

is ill-typed. Otherwise `T nat 4` would also type check (pretending we have naturals to help intuition).

---

If you want to write an application function (like Haskell's `$`) you can use

```
apply = 
    (λ (a b : *) →
     λ (f : a -> b) → 
     λ (x : a) → 
     f x)
```

Note that the above only applies to non-dependent `f`s. In the dependent case, `b` can depend on the actual value of type `a`, making things quite more complex, since now `b` is a function.

```
applyDep = 
    (λ (a : *) →
     λ (b : a -> *) →
     λ (f : ∀(x : a) -> b x) → 
     λ (x : a) → 
     f x)
```

An example (simplified syntax):

```
applyDep 
  Bool
  (λ (x : Bool) -> if x then Int else Char)
  (λ (x : Bool) -> if x then 4 else 'd')
  True
```

Above I am quite sloppy on the dependent function (the last lambda), since the `if` is ill-typed (different types for the branches), but you might get the rough idea. To write it more precisely, I would need something like the dependent match/case Coq has (or to rely to a dependent eliminator for `Bool`):

```ml
fun x: Bool =>
  match x as y return (if y then Int else Char) with
  | True  => 3
  | False => 'a'
  end
```

In the above "if", I had to make it clear that the type of the two branches is different (`Int` vs `Char`), yet it can be typed if we take that as the result of `g x`, where `g = fun y => if y then Int else Char`. Basically, the result type is now dependent the `x` value.